# Check a condition on a list and find exactly the number of elements that violate the condition

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I have a list like below:

```
A = [[-1 - 2*1j, -1 + 2*1j], [-5, -4], [7 - 9*1j, 7 + 9*1j], [9]]
```

I want to check whether all the elemets have the negative real part or not. 
In this case, the last two elements have a positive real part.

How can I identify the **number** of those elements that violate the condition?
In this case, I want to know that `A[2]` and `A [3]` violate the condition.

Comment: What is `I` in your example?

Comment: @DimitrisSkoufis it is the imaginary part, 1j

Comment: Use the `filter()` function to find all the elements that match a condition. In the condition, use the `any()` function to test if any of the elements of the list have a positive real part.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you after the *number* (i.e. n = 2) or the indices (i.e. [2, 3])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: A = [[-1 - 2*1j, -1 + 2*1j], [-5, -4], [7 - 9*1j, 7 + 9*1j], [9]]
In [2]: violates = [i for i, a in enumerate(A) if any([aa.real > 0 for aa in a])]
In [3]: violates
Out[3]: [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a function **p** that checks whether a condition on an object is true or false (also called a predicate), to find the elements in a list **L** that **violate** the condition, you can use:

```
list(filter(not(p),L))
```

Let's apply this to an example:

```
zs = [1 + 2j,5-3j,2,4j]
```

zs is a list of complex numbers, by the way in python a complex number is written as `a + bj`

```
print(list(filter(lambda z: z.real >= 0,zs)))
```

this will print the elements in zs that have a positive real part.

**P.S:** we use lambda to define an anonymous function, to make the code more compact, you can define a function the traditional way and pass its name to filter instead.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but I got this error: object of type 'filter' has no len()

Comment: @AmirRezaJalali I forgot to convert it to list, I will edit the post

Comment: Thanks for modification. the point is that I'm not looking for the number of elements that violate the condition. I want to know that zs [0], zs [1], zs [2] and zs [3] violate the condition. if the first two elements have the negative real part, I want to get an output like "zs [2] and zs [3]" that violate the condition.

Comment: @AmirRezaJalali then just remove len, it will give you a list of the elements